# What is the difference between "debate" and "discuss"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, word-difference

It appears to me that the meanings of these two verbs are the same.

Are they any different? If so, please tell me what is the difference between **debate** and **discuss**.

Comment: Have you checked the dictionary definitions?

Comment: @Mick I have checked English-Japanese dictionary. (I'm from Japan)

Comment: Have you checked online English dictionaries? Even Google provides reasonable definitions. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Note that *debate* is both a noun and a verb.

Comment: I have not checked online English dictionaries. I only checked English-Japanese dictionary.

Comment: Then you need to do more research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an explanation at [differencebetween.com](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-debate-and-vs-discussion/).

Usage of **debate**:

> The word ‘debate’ is generally used in the sense of ‘deliberation’. […]  It is important to know that there is an element of argument in a debate.
>
> This is primarily the reason why debate is considered a skill in developing one’s communication. It is a test of one’s communicative abilities. A debate is held as a kind of competition to prove one’s speaking and communicative ability

A **discussion** is normally used in meetings.

> A discussion normally is centered on a particular topic with assertions made by two or more people that do their best to establish the validity of the topic. […] a discussion is not held as a competition to judge a person’s speaking or communicative ability.

Comment: If you can move this to your original question, then we can provide an answer. I hate to be awkward, but that is the way we do things here.

Comment: @Mick isn't this the answer? The OP has answered their own question, it is even encouraged by SE.

Comment: It could be. I wasn't sure what the OP's intention was.